# Yield return changes the order of chained call methods

Tags: c#, yield-return

I am trying to understand yield return with IEnumerator. After trying the following simple example, I found that the last method in the chain executes first. Which I wasn't expecting.

```
    public static void Example()
    {
        List<Pet> pets =
               new List<Pet>{ new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                             new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 }
                             };

        var p1 = pets.ReturnPetAgeGreatThan2().ReturnPetAgeGreatThan4();

        foreach (var p in p1)
        {
            // Removed it to keep it simple  
            //Console.WriteLine("Pet Name:{0},Age:{1}", p.Name, p.Age);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static IEnumerable<Pet> ReturnPetAgeGreatThan2(this IEnumerable<Pet> p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThan2");

        foreach (var par in p)
        {
            if (par.Age > 2)
                yield return par;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Pet> ReturnPetAgeGreatThan4(this IEnumerable<Pet> p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThan4");

        foreach (var par in p)
        {
            if (par.Age > 4)
                yield return par;
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut

```
    I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThen4
    I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThen2
```

But as soon as I remove yield return, and change the function to use just return.The methods are called in order.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Pet> ReturnPetAgeGreatThan2(this IEnumerable<Pet> p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThen2");
        var result = p.Where(x => x.Age > 2);

        return result;
   }

    public static IEnumerable<Pet> ReturnPetAgeGreatThan4(this IEnumerable<Pet> p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThen4");
        var result = p.Where(x => x.Age > 4);
        return result;
     }
```

Output

```
     I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThen2
     I am in ReturnPetAgeGreatThen4
```

Any help to understand this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

With `yield return` you're creating an implicit enumerable. The compiler actually does a lot of code transformation in this case. The main point here is that the *state* of your method is saved whenever a value is returned.

So what happens here is basically that your first method returns an `IEnumerable` *immediately* when called, but the *code* that generates value for that will not run yet. That happens only when it's enumerated. That enumeration happens in your second method, which uses `foreach`. So you see the output of the second method first because the output of the first method only happens when the first value from the enumerable is generated.

In your second case you're actually not enumerating anything but rather return `IEnumerable`s that will generate / filter values only when enumerated. However, since your method body no longer includes `yield return` it will no longer be rewritten by the compiler to actually *be* an `IEnumerable` that generates values, thus being just a normal method and running immediately and in the order you expect.